# Layout one side curve shape in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanna to create Layout like this

[image]

And i achived this My problem is i don't know how to get curve shape in layout please help me.

[image]

Here is my **code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.HomeActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/sky">

    </RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1">

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: sorry i forgot...

Comment: y dont u use an image?

Comment: try to draw the shape on a canvas

Comment: because i don't want to increase my apk size. and i have only white background with curve how can i use??

Comment: one class doesn't have so much effect on your apk.Drawing on canvas is the best way to achieve that.other that you can add an image to set as background

Comment: I don't think so that this image will increase apk size that much..

Comment: if i am set the background how can i set my imageview on border because there is so many  devices out there

Answer (score 11):

i guess its too late, but it'll help others.

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                <item>
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid android:color="@color/colorSignInText"/>
                    </shape>
                </item>
                <item
                        android:top="100dp"
                        android:bottom="0dp"
                        android:left="-70dp"
                        android:right="-70dp">

                    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                           android:innerRadius="50dp"
                           android:shape="rectangle"
                           android:useLevel="true">

                        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
                        <corners

                                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                                android:topLeftRadius="260dp"
                                android:topRightRadius="260dp"/>

                    </shape>
                </item>
            </layer-list>
```

***Here take a look at the output:***

[image: Here take a look]

Answer (score 2):

Check out this library over here: https://github.com/developer-shivam/Crescento You can use this effect as is OR you can have a peek into source code and see the implementation for yourself!

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved using ONLY one drawable, but the look and feel is not so beautiful. Just  create a drawable xml, for ex: oval.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#fefefe"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Then you can design your layout somehow like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#fefefe"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/oval"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

<ImageView
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The screenshot is here: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using canvas and drawarc in onDraw( ) method.
For example:

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){ 
    Paint p = new Paint(); 
    RectF rectF = new RectF(50, 20, 100, 80); 
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
    canvas.drawArc (rectF, 90, 45, true, p); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<item  android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<item
    android:bottom="-120dp"
    android:top="120dp"
    android:left="-120dp"
    android:right="-120dp"
   >

    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid
            android:color="?android:colorBackground"/>
    </shape>


</item>
```

Comment: At first glance, your answer looks like a duplicate of an older answer by Abduaziz Kayumov. You should add details about how/why this works.